# Avoiding obsolete comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment

One particular problem is that when you point out a mistake in someone's answer, you have to check several times until he fixed it so you can delete your initial comment.

Otherwise your comment will likely be flagged as *obsolete*.

To avoid this issue, I was thinking about an option available when you post a comment, that would make the comment automatically auto-delete after one of four cases:

- the poster edits is answer,
- the poster acknowledge (with a little check box) your comment,
- the poster respond to you,
- a certain amount of time passes.

What do you think about such auto-deleting comments? What would be the downsides of this system?

Comment: What's the problem with having comments flagged as obsolete?

Comment: @arjafi I think it is wasting the time of moderators in a way that could be avoided.

Comment: Obsolete -flags we can handle quite quickly. In most cases it is relatively fast to ascertain that the comment has, indeed, served its purpose.  Thanks for asking, but this is really a non-problem from the point of view of mods. Of course, we probably have very many obsolete comments in threads nobody has bothered to visit for a year or more. This feature-request could help stop that problem from becoming worse. Provided all the commenters familiarized themselves with this feature (after it got implemented). Upvoting the good intention.

Comment: This seems related: [Can we have *temporary comments* that can be read and deleted?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20613)